# In meteor, I am trying to access the value of a <select> option when the user changes it

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events

In meteor, I am trying to set a session variable to the chosen value of a drop down menu.  Here's the html:

```
<select name="section">
    <option value=0>Choose a Class</option>
    <option value=3>Period 3</option>
    <option value=4>Period 4</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript:

```
Template.body.events({
            "change select[name='section']": function(event){
                Session.set("selectedPeriod",event.target.value);
            }

      });
```

I've read

[Meteor - update var on select change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450446/meteor-update-var-on-select-change)

but what I assumed would be analogous doesn't work either. Namely, in place of

```
event.target.value
```

using

```
$(event.target).val()
```

The code works fine if I just try to set the session variable to some dummy value, such as 4.

```
Template.body.events({
            "change select[name='section']": function(event){
                Session.set("selectedPeriod",4);
            }

      });
```

So my problem seems to be properly referencing the selected value.

Comment: that code seems to work fine. Maybe something else is the problem?

Comment: You were right. it was a string vs number problem. parseInt solved it.  Thank you.  I wouldn't have thought to look elsewhere without your guidance.