# meteor update-how to update the value?

Tags: meteor

Please help me solve this problem: I need to change the value after update process and so far, my code does not work.

This's the code:

```js
Template. edit_peralatan.events({
  'submit .peralatan': function (event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var currentPostId= Session.get ('this._id');
    var profil=Profil.findOne(currentPostId);

    var properties={
      kategori: $(event.target).find('[name=kategori]'). val(),
      jenama: $(event.target).find('[name=jenama]'). val(),
      trPerolehan: $(event.target).find('[name=trPerolehan]'). val(),
      noSiri: $(event.target).find('[name=noSiri]'). val(),
      noRedicare: $(event.target).find('[name=noRedicare]'). val(),    
    };

    Profil.update( currentPostId,{ $set: properties },
      function (error){
        if (error){
          alert (error.reason);
        } else {
          Router.go('list_inventori',{_id:currentPostId});
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Be specific - what doesn't work?

Comment: this's code. i don't know how to solve it. The values did not changed after  click  the button 'submit'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var currentPostId= Session.get ('this._id');` is almost surely the root cause of your error since it would make no sense to name a session variable `'this._id'` (a string). What was your actual intention here? Did you mean to have:

```
var currentPostId= this._id;
```

Comment: it's work.tq. one more question. Do you know how to get values from other template (collection) and create as select option (drop down), next selected value in form update.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450446/meteor-update-var-on-select-change